# How to search for a statistical procedure in R?

Tags: r

Is there an R package, website, or command that will allow one to search for a specific statistical procedure they desire?

For instance, if I wanted to find a package that had the Box-Cox Transformation, the website/package/command might return "MASS" and refer me to the `boxcox()` function.

It is fairly straightforward with something like Box-Cox, but I was hoping it would allow me to find more difficult procedures or search by what the function does ("Concatenating columns to a data frame" might turn up `cbind()`). Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[rseek](http://rseek.org/) is pretty good. More abstract semantic queries along the lines of your second example are hard anywhere.

Also, see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102056/how-to-search-for-r-materials) from the [R-faq listing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/faq) there.

Comment: +1: That's a really useful SO thread there. Pretty much reduces my question to a repost :P.

Answer (score 14):

The [sos package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos) lets you search the help documentation for all cran packages from within R itself.

Comment: Oh no. You beat me to it. I will delete my answer!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes I just go to crantastic and search for keywords

[Search for Box Cox on Crantastic](http://crantastic.org/search?q=Box+Cox)

Answer (score 4):

I would try two things.  One is the ?? help search in R, so for Box-Cox I would do

```
??cox
```

which should list packages or functions with that text

The other is to try the http://www.rseek.org/ site which is like google just for R.